# db2 - how to get list of all of the Db2 instances on computer

Tags: security, db2, logins, db2-luw

I have several Linux servers and on them may be one or more Db2 instances. Db2 instances can be from different Db2 versions.

For security audit I need to write some simple bash script to check for some "dbm cfg" settings on all Linux servers. I have some tool that allows me to connect to Linux servers with root access and then I am able to execute any bash command on remote Linux server.

QUESTION: What I am having a problem is, how to get the list of Db2 instances on Linux server with root user without knowing the Db2 instance owners or Db2 instance names?

When I get the owners I can "sudo" or "su" to that Db2 instance owner Linux user and execute "db2 get dbm cfg" command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`db2greg` command](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=tools-db2greg):

```
db2greg -dump
```

Comment: Above command returns several info, but it is excellent point. Above command returns several rows and columns delimitered by comma. To get **instance names** in output from above command it is required to return fourth column when filtering first column with "I" and second column with "DB2" where column delimiter is comma. Like:

`db2greg -dump | gawk -F, '$1=="I" && $2="DB2" {print $4}'`

Answer (score 1):

db2ilist command will list instances on the server.
https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=commands-db2ilist-list-instances

[db2 install path]/bin/db2ilist

Comment: db2ilist is working only if you are already connected to instance with instance user. It also displays only instances for Db2 version for current instance. If there are more then one Db2 products installed and/or I don't know the instance names, then "db2greg -dump" is correct answer.

Comment: db2ilist will list all instances under one product - if you have multiple products, then yes, you would need to use multiple commands, but output is much simpler than db2greg.

`[root@devserver ~]# [db2 install path]/bin/db2ilist
db2inst1
db2inst2
db2inst3`